# The empty set consists of the intersection of all the closed half-spaces that contain it.

Tags: convex-analysis

I want to prove that the empty set consists of the intersection of all the closed half-spaces that contain it. While I am able to do the proof for every closed and convex proper subset of k-dimensional real space  using the strict-separation theorem, I am facing difficulty in proving it for the empty set.

Comment: Take any hyperplane and shift it in the orthogonal direction. Then the half-spaces on the "outsides" of that middle slice have empty intersection.

Comment: “All the closed half-spaces that contain it” means, in this case, simply, “All closed half-spaces”.

Comment: Alternatively, since you've already proven it for non-empty closed, convex sets, just note two non-empty,  closed, convex sets that are disjoint.